# Specify grouping variable in a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, grouping, correlation

I wrote a function to ease the visualization of a bunch of correlations that I was doing. Specifically, I was interested in viewing bivariate relationships side by side in `ggplot2` panels with the p-value and rho value printed directly on the graph. I wrote this function using the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

grouped_cor_ <- function(data, x, y, group.col){
  x <- lazyeval::as.lazy(x)
  y <- lazyeval::as.lazy(y)
  cor1 <- lazyeval::interp(~ cor.test(x, y,method="spearman",na.action = "na.exclude")$estimate, x = x, y = y)
  corp <- lazyeval::interp(~ cor.test(x, y,method="spearman", na.action = "na.exclude")$p.value, x = x, y = y)
  mnx <- lazyeval::interp(~ mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), x = x, y = y)
  mny <- lazyeval::interp(~ mean(y, na.rm=TRUE), x = x, y = y)

  summarise_(group_by(data, Species), rho=cor1, pval=corp, xcoord=mnx, ycoord=mny)
}
```

This is the data frame that I am using to print the statistics from the correlation:

```
grouped_cor_(data=iris, x=~Petal.Width, y=~Petal.Length)
```

Then this is the function that calls the plot:

```
corHighlight <- function(Data, x, y){
  cordf<-grouped_cor_(Data, x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))
  cordf$prho <- paste("rho=",round(cordf$rho,3), "\n p-value=",round(cordf$pval,3), sep=" ")
  plt<-ggplot(Data, aes_q(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
    geom_text(data=cordf, aes_q(x=substitute(xcoord), 
                            y=substitute(ycoord), 
                            label=substitute(prho)), colour='red') + 
    geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.3) +
    facet_wrap(~Species)
  print(plt)
}


corHighlight(Data=iris, 
         x=Petal.Width, 
         y=Petal.Length)
```

The function, though a little clunky, works well now with one small detail that I can't seem to figure out. I can't figure out how to add a column specification for the grouping variable. Right now the function is tied to the `iris` dataset because it only accepts a grouping variable named `species'. My question then is how do I separate this function from the iris dataset and generalized the grouping variable.

Can anyone recommend an efficient way of doing this? Happy to accept any comments that improve the function as well.

Comment: Couldn't you just pass a formula argument in to `corHighlight`? Then if you had two factors it could be `form=~facA+facB`.

Comment: I don't quite see how that specifies the column. Possible to elaborate?

Comment: If you want a tested answer then produce a dataset with the required structure.

Comment: I think I have. The issue is that I don't know how to specify the grouping variable in the function. The resulting dataset is what I want but the function that creates it is specific to the iris data set. I'd like to have an argument in the function that specifies the grouping column.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to specify two factors with one being row and the other being column.

Comment: I see. So the factor itself and the levels of the factor. Well that would be nice.

Comment: I imagined you pass the argument to facet_wrap as a formula, which would make the facet()-ting arrangement dependent on the call rather than fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would let you pass a single grouping factor to your helper function. Does require using `group_by_` since I extract the name from the formula as a character but then coerce back it to a name:

```
grouped_cor_ <- function(data, x, y, form){
  x <- lazyeval::as.lazy(x)
  y <- lazyeval::as.lazy(y); fac <- as.name(as.character(form)[2])
  cor1 <- lazyeval::interp(~ cor.test(x, y,method="spearman",na.action = "na.exclude")$estimate, x = x, y = y)
  corp <- lazyeval::interp(~ cor.test(x, y,method="spearman", na.action = "na.exclude")$p.value, x = x, y = y)
  mnx <- lazyeval::interp(~ mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), x = x, y = y)
  mny <- lazyeval::interp(~ mean(y, na.rm=TRUE), x = x, y = y)

  summarise_( group_by_(data, fac), rho=cor1, pval=corp, xcoord=mnx, ycoord=mny)
}
```

To illustrate what I said in the comment (allow the function to accept a formula that can be processed by `facet_wrap``:

```
corHighlight <- function(Data, x, y, form){
  cordf<-grouped_cor_(Data, x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y), form=substitute(form))
  cordf$prho <- paste("rho=",round(cordf$rho,3), "\n p-value=",round(cordf$pval,3), sep=" ")
  plt<-ggplot(Data, aes_q(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
    geom_text(data=cordf, aes_q(x=substitute(xcoord), 
                            y=substitute(ycoord), 
                            label=substitute(prho)), colour='red') + 
    geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.3) +
    facet_wrap(form)
  print(plt)
}
corHighlight(Data=iris, 
         x=Petal.Width, 
         y=Petal.Length, form = ~Species)
```

Comment: This does indeed work for the `corHighlight` function but using the same logic, I don't seem to be able to apply it to the `grouped_cor_` function. Any ideas on how to extend it to there?

Comment: If you only need it to accept a single grouping name I can do that pretty easily. Is that enough?